# Time delay before redirecting

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

I have a application I am designing in C# that requries a welcome screen which leads to a login screen. I want the welcome screen to be on display for around 3 seconds before loading the logon page. Is there a timeout function like javascripts setTimeout that I can use to do this?

Comment: What kind of application? WinForms? WPF?

Comment: In other words, you want a splash screen. There are several duplicate questions and tutorials that show how to do that

Comment: You probably don't need a logon page either if your database or middle tier uses Windows authentication. The OS already knows who the user is and connects to databases, services as that user

Comment: @itsme86 its a winforms application.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos its a specification of the course i am doing - the only way i have seen how to do so far uses threading which I havent covered yet so I am reluctant to use without understanding them